# I have a table with 2 columns where the second one contains 2 cells in an excel file and i want to convert it to a dictionary using Python

Tags: python, pandas

[the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abf13.png)

I want to obtain the following dictioanary :
{S[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abf13.png): 1,2 , S[2]: 1,3 , S[3]:2,3 , S[4]: 1,2 , S[5] : 1,3}

Comment: Use `df.groupby('Order')['Stages'].apply(list).to_dict()`

Comment: i get the following result {1: [1], 2: [1], 3: [2], 4: [1], 5: [1], '': [2, 3, 3, 2, 3]} while i need to obtain this : {S[1]: 1,2 , S[2]: 1,3 , S[3]:2,3 , S[4]: 1,2 , S[5] : 1,3}

Comment: hmmm, it is not valid dictonary, so impossible get it.